# Impedance of USB-A cable when disabling data pins with tape

Tags: usb

I have an interesting situation.

I have a USB-A 2.0 (4 pins) to USB-C cable. I need to fully disable the data connection, so I used a painter's tape to cover the two middle pins (D+ and D-).

When I connect my phone to the computer, it works as intended. The phone simply charges, does not show as a connected device. Before, without the tape, it would charge and also connect as a storage.

I have another device (a modem), however, that is behaving strange:

- Without the tape, connected to a charger: it charges only (as expected)
- Without the tape, connected to a computer: it charges and the device shows it is connected to another device (as expected)
- With the tape, connected to a charger: it charges and the modem flags it is connected to another device (NOT expected)
- With the tape, connected to a computer: same as above (but the computer does not show a device is connected to it).

How would you explain that?

Am I right to assume that this modem uses very short impedance, and maybe the tape is causing some impedance, so it senses a data connection is available?

I also tried to mask with a paper, with same results as above.

Any idea why the modem might be sensing there is data when I cover the data pins?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe the modem senses the current draw and flags it as a connected device

Comment: The modem is expecting either a dedicated charger, with the right signaling on the USB C resistor pin or usb data pins with a charging standard (Apple, Samsung, QC, USB PD, etc), or its assuming its connected to a computer. It may not be designed to be dumb enough to charge only without signaling. The phone is smarter, and understands 3 states, not just two.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried generic chargers too, not only the original charger!